# is there a way to read pickle csv files in c++

Tags: c++, pickle

Hi I am coming from a python background and a lot of my data is saved using to_pickle from the pandas libary in the case of dfs or pickle.dump in the case of python dictionaries. I have been googling around and all I can find is python related content. So is pickle available just for python or is there a way to read the data frame data using c++?

Comment: How large is your data? Megabytes, or terabytes? How often is it changed? Every milliseconds, or once per week? What operating system do you code for? What will happen to you on software failure?

Comment: And what did you try? Show some [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The `pickle` function is indeed specific to Python.

However, [Python](https://python.org/) is open source, and coded in C (and Python).

You could read more about [extending and embedding Python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html).

Then you could call C++ code (in particular, your C++ functions declared `extern "C"`) from Python or (with efforts) Python code from a C++ program.

You probably could find open source libraries in C++ parsing CSV files.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1120140/841108) question.

Another approach is (if possible) to choose a simpler data format (like [JSON](https://json.org/)) for which both Python and C++ libraries exist.

Or use some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database.

Or (on Linux at least) use inter-process communication facilities (e.g. [unix(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets) between a Python program/process and a C++ one.

Comment: I can parse csv files its just that the vast majority maybe 95% of my data is stored in pickle. I think I will consider your json suggestion as it seems like a good option for my case thanks